# Count all files with specific type in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm kinda new to coding, and I need to count files with specific type in my folder, but I don't know how to do it using fs module!

My current code:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    console.log(files.length)
});
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathextnamepath) like this:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const path = require('path');
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    const result = files.filter(f => path.extname(f).toLowerCase() === yourExtension).length
    console.log(result)
});
```

Also, as mentioned by MegaMix_Craft, take care about the variable `yourExtension`. It has to have the dot `.value`. As an example it should be `.js` not only `js`.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Comment: If `files` is `undefined` I think your `dir` value is wrong. If you want to read current directory you can use `__dirname`.

Comment: Also please note that you have to type for example `.jpg` in `yourExtension` and not just `jpg`

Comment: Yes, good point @MegaMix_Craft